# Not able to make ajax call from a Web View in Windows 10 Cordova App

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

We are developing a Windows 10 cordova app. As per our requirement we have added a Web View (`<x-ms-webview id="id-web-view" height="100%" width="100%"></x-ms-webview>`) inside an HTML page and loading resources (HTML, JS, CSS etc) inside Web View from AppData\Local\Packages\LocalState directory. HTML, CSS, JS and other resources are loading perfectly fine.

We are not able make any AJX call from web View (embedded page). Getting Error- **XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied**. AJAX calls are woring fine for parent HTML.

Seems its a CORS issue. I have tried various JQuery and other option to enable CORS. Its not working.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: CORS issue should be solved by the server side. Do you have access to the server that your ajax are requesting to?

Comment: Yes I can access the server. It will be highly appreciated if you can write down server side changes require to enable CORS

Answer (score 1):

Customize the content security policy in the **meta tag** **http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"** as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript. For details, see go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521 add meta tag http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"

Please visit http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists/

Comment: Are you able make ajax calls in android/iOS? Call ajax function as **yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foobar('somedata')");**  If ajax calls working fine tin android/iOS there must be problem with windows platform [see enable cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) other wise enable http://enable-cors.org/server.html. Please also visit https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md

Comment: Yes iOS and Android is working fine. Also in Windows I am abale to make Ajax call from Parent page. Its not woking only with embedded WebView That we have added in index page of Windows app to load HTML from appData folder

Comment: @Shamse have you tried use iframe instead of x-ms-webview? Maybe a demo project that reproduced the problem?

Comment: We cant use iFrame as we have to callcordova plugins  also we are loading data from appData directory. iFarme will not support this

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS, simply add the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {your domain} or {*}" to your server side's website.

The steps of adding response header is dependent on your server. You can refer to [CORS on the server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) for most used servers.

Let me know, if the server by your side isn't in that list, or some other specific problems appear.